# how to create my own Unsubscribe link?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm using MSSQL Database mailing system for sending reports to my clients.(those reports have parameters which are taken from my database).

the thing is some users they don't want to get those reports (email).

What I have done to do this manually is, I created a field inside my table as a bit, if its 0 it will send email if its 1 it will not.

Now my question is, how can I do this by having an unsubscribe link inside the email so client can do this automatically?

Appreciate your help

Comment: If you are using some kind of automatic mailier it probably has a feature for it already. If not, create a php file that will process a `GET` request. In the report mail add a link like `http://www.yourdomain.com/stop_sending_mail.php?mail=emailaddress`. You can add more information in case you need that or want to perform auth test. In your php file you check the emailaddress and update the database.

Answer (score -1):

Redirect to Unsubscribe form to your website, ask user to enter email again, use that email and execute delete query to your database.